# WebException with ContentType Multipart/form-data

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, multipartform-data

i am trying to make a httpwebrequest, to connect with a api of a customer. This works for most of the apis, but one of them requires ContentType = "multipart/form-data", which why i have to add it to my request. But since i added it, i get an System.Net.WebException at the line where i am using the GetResponse-method. My JsonRequest is correct, because i tried it at a demo site, but i do not know what to do with this Exception! If i do not at the ContentType multipart/form-data, i get an error msg from the api, that "not all parameters are set correctly". 
I hope you can help me!

```
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = requestMethode;
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        string strResponse = "";
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse httpResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()) // error here
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(strResponse);
        return jobject;
    }
```

Thx a lot!

Comment: What is the exception message that you get?

Comment: If you are specifying `multipart/form-data` Content-Type, why are you sending some `JSON` payload to the server? Those are very different things.

Comment: @Darin, because the api doesnt require a filerequest, which is why i am going the other way. But unfortunitly i have to set the contenttype anyway.

Comment: @Yacoub its a 500 internal server error

Comment: @Darin: This is the api doc: https://i.materialise.com/api/docs/cart-item-creation-api/

Comment: @Maermot, yes, I can see the doc. It requires a `multipart/form-data` encoded request. So make sure you respect this encoding if you want this to work. If you are unsure about what `multipart/form-data` is don't hesitate to consult the specification: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt In your example you have just set the Content-Type request header to the proper value but the body of the request that you are sending is very different from how a `multipart/form-data` encoded request should look like.

Comment: can u give me an example of a valid request? I do not know why i cannot send my jsonstring, which works on their demo page

Comment: You cannot send a jsonstring because a `multipart/form-data` encoding is different from JSON. Did you read the spec I have linked to in my previous comment? I strongly encourage you to do so in order to better familiarize yourself with this protocol. Otherwise it might be tough for you to make a proper request.

Comment: ah sry i do not see ur edit. I will try to figure it out and give Feedback :) Thx

Comment: ok multipart/form-data is for file submits... but i have no file to upload, so i dont get it how to make a proper request without a file ...

Comment: No, `multipart/form-data` is not only for file submits. It can be used to combine different content types in a single payload.

Comment: @Darin I am trying it with the `RestSharp Restrequest` and figured it out for APIs with Content-Type: application/json.. But how to request just json strings to a API, which required multipart/form-data, i am really frustrated. Can you help me please?

Comment: No need to use a third party library. Simply read the specification of the `multipart/form-data` HTTP and format it accordingly using an `HttpWebRequest` that's built in .NET. You can also checkout my answer which might give you some hints at the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the remote endpoint that you are trying to call requires a `multipart/form-data` encoded request. I strongly suggest you reading the [`corresponding specification`](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) to better familiarize yourself with the exact payload that needs to be sent over the wire. This way you will better understand where the problem with your code is.

And once you have read the spec you could come up with the following:

```
string json = "PUT THE SAMPLE JSON TAKEN FROM HERE https://i.materialise.com/api/docs/cart-item-creation-api/";
var url = "https://imatsandbox.materialise.net/web-api/cartitems/register";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
var boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
boundary = "--" + boundary;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.WriteLine(boundary);
    writer.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"blob\"");
    writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: application/json");
    writer.WriteLine();
    writer.Write(json);
    writer.WriteLine();
    writer.WriteLine(boundary + "--");
}

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return JObject.Parse(strResponse);
}
```

Also notice that I have removed the meaningless `try/catch` in which you were simply rethrowing.

Comment: wow, Thanks a lot! it works. i will try to understand the theory for the next time!

Comment: No, not for the next time. You'd better understand the theory right now. Personally I would be extremely afraid running code I don't understand how/why it works. If I were you I wouldn't ever trust anyone on the internet providing me some code snippets and putting them in my production code without understanding the basics of this code. The fact that some code *works* doesn't mean at all that this code is optimal or that you should use it in production.

Comment: of course not. Its just on the sandbox and i will understand it on the sandbox, before going on the production. Then again, thank you